# Salesforce certification change plan!

Tags: certification

I come across this change while surfing and was surprising to see.. Anyone know much about this change? Share to help other. Make us more understandable..

Thank you![image: Ref pics]

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Why there is a change in certification.. This forum have some MVPs and I though though could brief us the reason for this change.. This might be discussed in MVP meet...

Comment: First of all, it's Salesforce's call to make changes in the certification and I doubt the MVP's will have a detailed explanation to why they're changing the certs. What you're asking is primarily opinion based and should be asked on an alternative forum. Here is an FAQ page for the new certs, which I hope will answer any further questions you have - http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-Developer-Certification-Transition-Process. Alternatively you can open a case with Salesforce - http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-case.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation.. Have a great week...

Comment: I agree with @Bachovski. As far as I know there hasn't been any public statement in regards to *why* this has been done. I however fully agree, and have always considered the 401 certification rather easy and very little preparation for the 501 certification.